# Sprockets manifest file - dual Rails 3 / Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I was wondering if anyone had the *pleasure* to manage a dual boot live environment (RoR 3 and RoR 4, side by side - for the option to rollback) where I'm using sprockets in both version.

However, in rails 3, we synch manifest.yml across servers, for rails4, I now have manifest-*.json...
I need to do this with zero down time, assets are served from CDN. But mapping of asset to digested asset name is done in all servers of course.

Thoughts?

What I have at hand so far is:

```
module Sprockets
  module Rails
    module Helper

    @@old_manifest_format

      def asset_digest_path(path, options = {})
        if manifest = assets_manifest
          yaml_dictionary ||=YAML.load_file('./public/assets/manifest.yml') rescue {}
          if digest_path = (yaml_dictionary[path] || manifest.assets[path])
            return digest_path
          end
        end

        if environment = assets_environment
          if asset = environment[path]
            return asset.digest_path
          end
        end
      end

    end
  end
end
```

But there got to be a better way, or is there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, the only viable solution is an initialiser, config/initizilier/sprockets_patch.rb:

```
if Rails.env.production?
  SPROCKETS_OLD_MANIFEST_FORMAT = YAML.load_file('./public/assets/manifest.yml') rescue {}
end
```

and than the patch itself, lib/core_ext/sprockets/asset_digest_path.rb:

```
#### Temporary override to allow Rails 4 to work with rails 3 manifest.yaml
module Sprockets
  module Rails
    module Helper

      def asset_digest_path(path, options = {})
        if manifest = assets_manifest
          if digest_path = (SPROCKETS_OLD_MANIFEST_FORMAT[path] || manifest.assets[path])
            return digest_path
          end
        end

        if environment = assets_environment
          if asset = environment[path]
            return asset.digest_path
          end
        end
      end

    end
  end
end
```